# WPF can't load other project resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have one project which centralize all the resources, called DmUiCommon.Portable. This project is a Portable Class Library.

In another project I've created a WPF Window which takes the resource string from the common project. To achieve this I reference the common project like this:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:DmUiCommon.Properties;assembly=DmUiCommon.Portable"
```

And when I want to load an specific resource, I do it in this way:

```
Title="{x:Static p:Resources.DmStrSettings}"
```

Everything seems okay in the designer and the App compiles, but when I Run it, a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException is fired, saying the PublicKeyToken od DmUiCommon.Portable is null an that this file can not be found.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your references set right. I had this problem occur when Project B used an assembly (like WPG) in XAML, but Project A actually created the instance of a Project B class. Adding the WPF reference to Project A is necessary for the XAML parser to work in this way. Referencing Project B in Project A is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have an article in the code project that describes howto do it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433476/Structuring-Your-XAML-Sources

At least if I understand you correctly and you want to use resources from different assemblies.